# SUM column values based on two rows in the same tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have one table like below in my SQL server.

```
Trans_id    br_code bill_no amount
1           22      111     10
2           22      111     20
3           22      111     30
4           22      111     40
5           22      111     10
6           23      112     20
7           23      112     20
8           23      112     20
9           23      112     30
```

and I want desired output like below table

```
s.no    br_code  bill_no    amount
1       22       111        110
2       23       112        90
```

Comment: This is a very simple aggregation query.  `group by` is a basic part of the SQL language.  You should spend a little time learning the language.

Comment: Hint -  `select transid,br_code,aggrigatefunctionforsum(bill_no_amount) from table group by columns with non aggirgatefunctions in there select`

Comment: Is it always the same `bill_no` per `br_code`? Then your database design is bad and you should normalize the table. If not: What output do you want: one row per `br_code` + `bill_no`, one row per `br_code`, or one row per `bill_no`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select br_code, bill_no, sum(amount)
from TABLE
group by br_code, bill_no
```